# Dynamically add attribute to struts2 UI tag

Tags: struts2, attributes

Is there a way to dynamically add an attribute to a struts 2, tag UI tag such as a textfield?

The reason is that I want to add a `readOnly` form field attribute to an `<s:textfield/>`, depending on an action's method result. I cannot use `readOnly="%{isReadOnly()}"` since once the attribute is defined, the form element is read-only, no matter what value it has. And wrapping each form field into an `<s:if/>` tag is pretty cumbersome and results in a lot of code duplication.

I would also like to avoid JavaScript for interoperability reasons and for not relying on the browser's scripting settings.

Comment: I'm not sure, if i have understood your questions, there are 2 ways to manipulate the DOM, you can generate it from the server side, then transfer it or you can manipulate it using JS. Can you post some code to show your problem.

Comment: Reworded the question so it should be more understandable. Good question btw, I can see value in this and I don't think there is an obvious answer...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 As I stated I'd like to avoid JS but use server-side evaluation. There is a `boolean isReadOnly()` method in the action class. So if this method returns true, there should be an `<s:textfield readonly="readonly"/>`, and if it returns false, the struts element should be just `<s:textfield/>`

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is to use the built in struts2 functionality then one easy option is to render your view with freemarker, which readily supports the dynamic addition of attributes.

If you are using conventions, it is VERY trivial you just need to create a file with a ".ftl" extension, if you are using xml it is also very easy just use the freemarker result type (see [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/Freemarker%20Support.html) for greater description):

```
<action name="test" class="package.Test">
  <result name="success" type="freemarker">/WEB-INF/content/testView.ftl</result>
</action>
```

Here is example view using a map to dynamically add attributes (example also taken from liked page):

```
<@s.textfield name="test" dynamicAttributes={"placeholder":"input","foo":"bar"}/>
```

The dynamicAttributes would be extremely useful in all JSP UI tags but alas it is not currently implemented.

**NOTE**:  There is one error/omission in the above link. It tells you to add the following line which causes an error in my environment (simply the line is not needed).

```
<#assign s=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/struts.tld"] />
```

That is, this line in a file *all by it self* is sufficient for rendering a text element, no explicit tag library declaration needed!

```
<@s.textfield name="test" dynamicAttributes={"placeholder":"input","foo":"bar"}/>
```

There are a number of advantages to using freemarker over plain JSPs, so taking a moment to explore the syntax and using it for this one case may prove useful later.

Comment: From what I've understood you can only set the attribute's _value_, but not the _entire_ attribute dynamically. I tried approaches like `<@s.textfield dynamicAttributes={getReadOnlyAttribute()}/>` (with the custom method returning the string `\"readonly\":\"readonly\"`) and `<@s.textfield getReadOnlyAttribute()}/>` (returning the string `readonly=\"readonly\"`). Both attempts also with the $ and %{} notation. Each time, either a struts or freemarker parsing exception occurred.

Comment: You must return a map, not a string which can be interpreted as a map.

Comment: Thank you. Still no success, unfortunately. Here's what I've tried: `dynamicAttributes=...` and then `%{getReadOnlyAttribute()}, {%{getReadOnlyAttribute()}}, {${getReadOnlyAttribute()}}, ${getReadOnlyAttribute()}, {${action.getReadOnlyAttribute()}}, ${action.getReadOnlyAttribute()}, {%{#action.getReadOnlyAttribute()}}, %{#action.getReadOnlyAttribute()}`; with the method returning a Map<String, Object>. However, the method is never called as Freemarker always "expected other sign". How can I call a the method to pass those attribute values?

Comment: I looked into it and tried as many permutations as you have! End result no luck. I'm tempted to extend the struts2 textfield jsp tag with a dynamic attributes parameter which takes a map and does what you and I would expect it to do with that map.